# How to find vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets-7.0.dll

Tags: python, tkinter, vtk

I am using VTK 7 on Windows 7-64 via Python 3.4.  I have done quite a lot with it already, but need a GUI.  I am trying to use Tkinter examples that come with VTK, but the file

vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets-7.0.dll

is referenced in vtkLoadPythonTkWidgets but is not available.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: while I do not have a solution, I simply want to mention that `Qt` offers a `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`. [Here is an example on how to use it](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Widgets/EmbedPyQt).